# WiFi signal level jumps to maximum

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm trying to solve some WiFi issue I have at office.
There is a high rate of packet drop:

[image]

But the most weird thing is the histograms (in both info and lhist) show a lot of "jumps" from the average signal level to the maximum:

[image]

I've never seen something like that. What could be the reason for such an issue?

Comment: Update your Wireless Driver and the Router firmware.

Comment: @John I have no access to the router and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and it has not further update. Anyway from `lshw` I know that I have `RTL8821AE` with driver `5.15.0-41-generic`. On the manufacturer site I cannot find anything for Linux: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8821ae-software

Comment: I am not sure what else to suggest - those are the things that affect wireless and packet loss if you otherwise have good machine access to the router.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use another wi-fi router. I work before on a TP-link and when I changed to the Asus I have no problem with signal and quality.